# PHP - приведение объекта к типу int

Tags: php, ооп

Имею класс variant, который динамически хранит в себе данные о самом значении и его типе(номер типа, кастомный, обязателен, так как может быть UINT тип, а может быть и INT, важен для передачи значения в другую программу). Можно ил сделать автоматическое приведение объекта в типу, если я например выполню код:

```
echo intval($intVariant);
echo floatval($floatVariant);
```

Так же что бы можно было привести к массиву, например, массиву тех же variant'ов:

```
echo intval($variants['name']);
```

Comment: как-то так `array_map('intval', array_column($variants, 'name') )`, но не понятно что у вас там за массив

Comment: Забудьте про intval, strval и им подобные. Используйте явное приведение типов, аля (int), (string). Увидите ощутимую разницу  в быстродействии.